# Trouble running example django code

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, cheeseshop

Im trying to learn Django by looking at examples, but Im having a bit of a problem running the examples I find.

I downloaded 'cheeserator' from https://github.com/jacobian/cheeserater
and I tried running it with *python manage.py runserver*
but I get the following error -

> Error: Can't find the file
>   'settings.py' in the directory
>   containing 'manage.py'. It appears
>   you've customized things. You'll have
>   to run django-admin.py, passing it
>   your settings module. (If the file
>   settings.py does indeed exist, it's
>   causing an ImportError somehow.)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a settings.py file.

As per the instructions in the link provided:

Then you'll want to create a settings.py file in this directory containing::

```
from settings_template import *

# Override any settings you like here.
```

Or if you don't want to override anything rename settings_template.py to settings.py